# Why do you just delete an item? Is it possible to delete the selected item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function to add inputs to a form through "append" and I have another button that removes the inputs entered. For this, with "last-child" I delete the last generated div but from here the button stops working and I can not eliminate other elements previously introduced.

That is, if I only enter a single element it deletes it without problems and yet when I have several elements it only deletes a single time and the delete function stops working.

Do you know what is due?

```js
$( ".add_button" ).click(function() {
  var first = document.getElementById('producto');
var options = first.innerHTML + options;

var newElement = '<div class="juan"><div class="form-group"><label>Producto</label><select class="form-control select2 producto" name="producto[]" id="producto" required>' + options + '</select></div><div class="form-group"><label>Cantidad</label><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control" value=""/></div><div class="form-group"><label for="nombre">Nº albarán proveedor</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="albaran_proveedor" name="albaran_proveedor[]" placeholder="El número de albarán del proveedor..."></div><div class="form-group"><label for="precio">Precio</label><input type="number" class="form-control" id="precio" name="precio[]" placeholder="Precio...(Solo números y punto para decimales) "></div><div class="form-group"><label>Fecha recepción:</label><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div><input type="text" id="fecha_recepcion" name="fecha_recepcion[]" class="form-control" data-mask></div><br><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button btn btn-warning">Quitar producto</a></div>';
$( ".field_wrapper" ).append( $(newElement) );
$('.select2').select2();


 
});
$(".field_wrapper").on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div.juan:last-child > div.form-group').remove();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help]. Great job including most of the code. Please note that Stack Snippets (what you've used) are for **runnable** examples, but your example isn't runnable (doesn't have jQuery, or the buttons, or the field wrapper, etc.). For non-runnable examples, just use a code block. But ideally, provide a runnable example; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I will take it into account in future occasions.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the `div.form-group` *within* the `div.juan`, not the `div.juan` itself. So it continues to be the last child, and subsequent attempts to remove it just don't remove anything (since it's already been removed).

You probably want:

```
$('div.juan:last-child').remove();
```

That said, it will only remove the `div.juan` if it's also the last child in its container (which it probably will be in your case). If you meant the last `div.juan`, you want either jQuery's `:last` selector extension, or its `last` method:

```
$('div.juan:last').remove();
// or
$('div.juan').last().remove();
```

---

In a comment you've said you want to be able to delete any of the inputs, even if it's not the last one. And looking closely at the HTML you have in a string, I see you're putting a `.remove_button` in each input's structure. That makes it easy to delete the structure associated with that specific button, by using `closest` to find the `div.juan` it's in and then removing that:

```
$(".field_wrapper").on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("div.juan").remove(); // <===============
});
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. I have tried what you have told me and I deleted the last div "juan", but I think I explained wrong. I intend to be able to individually delete one of the groups of generated inputs. That is, if I have generated 3 inputs, I have filled 2 and one I have left empty, I would like to be able to erase that empty input, however, as I have it now, it always erases the last generated. Did I explain correctly ?, I'm sorry for my English but I'm Spanish and it costs me a little.

Comment: @abel-k - I've updated the answer. I should have been able to figure that out from the HTML you have in the string. But for next time, again, you want to remove the extraneous so that you're not burying things in the middle of a lot of text, etc. :-)